# Substitute for triangle inequality for Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, information-theory

I know that the Kullback-Leibler divergence does not satisfy the triangle inequality. But is there a substitute, maybe in one of the forms below?
$$
D(P|Q)\leq C\left(D(P|R)+D(R|Q)\right), \quad\text{for some} C> 0
$$
$$
D(P|Q)\leq D(R|P)+D(P|R)+D(R|Q)+D(Q|R),
$$
$$
D(P|Q)\leq D(R|P)^a+D(R|Q)^a\quad\text{for some } a> 0
$$

Comment: Perhaps it is better that $ C $ should be declared and a value range $ a $ is specified so that the inequalities become clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$\text{}$1. Relative entropy does not behave like a distance measure. Regarding your question, please check for the Pythagorean theorem of relative entropy.

$\text{}$2. One can define the Jensen-Shannon divergence between $P$ and $Q$ as $${{D(P|M)+D(Q|M)}\over2},$$where $M$ is the midpoint between $P$ and $Q$. It has been proved that the square root of the Jensen-Shannon divergence satisfies the triangle inequality.

There exist sequences $P_n$, $Q_n$, and $R_n$ such that $D(P_n|Q_n)$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity and $D(Q_n|R_n)$ tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity, but $D(P_n|Q_n)$ does not tend to zero as $n$ tends to infinity. This result will provide counterexamples to several suggested inequalities.

> Can you link me to Pythagorean theorem you mention?

Regarding properties of relative entropy, please see the following for discussion of $I$-divergence properties. I was referring to the parallelogram identity (identity 7).

https://www.clsp.jhu.edu/~sanjeev/520.447/Spring00/I-divergence-properties.ps

> And maybe also to a description of the sequences you mention?

First construct three probability measures $P$, $Q$, and $R$ such that $D(P|Q)$ and $D(Q|R)$ are finite but $D(P|R)$ is infinite. This is possible if the sample space is countable by choosing $P$ more heavy tailed than $Q$ that should be more heavy tailed than $R$. Then let $P_n$ be the probability measure$$\left({1\over{n}}\right)P+\left(1-{1\over n}\right)R$$ and $Q_n$ be the probability measure$$\left({1\over n}\right)Q+\left(1-{1\over n}\right)R$$ and $R_n = R$.

Comment: This is a good answer, but at the same time seems to stop short of fully answering the question, as the Jensen-Shannon divergence is not simply a function of $D(P|Q)$ and $D(Q|R)$. I take your word that the probability measures you mention in your last section exist, but it doesn't entirely rule out an analog of the triangle inequality, since the desired function of  $D(P|Q)$ and $D(Q|R)$ might itself approach infinity for certain values of its arguments. Perhaps none of this matters, but I'd be curious about a comprehensive answer to the question, if the question can be made rigorous enough.

Answer (score 2):

For the binary KL-divergernce we have the following "approximate triangle-inequality":
$$
D(a\,\|\,c)+D(c\,\|\,b)=D(a\,\|\,b) + (c-a)D'(c\,\|\,b),
$$
where $D'(c\,\|\,b) = \log\frac{c(1-b)}{(1-c)b}$.

I wonder if one can show something similar for the case of general probability distributions.

Comment: I think this will generalise. You just have to write $D(R\|Q) + D(Q\|P) = D(R\|P) + \big(D(R\|Q) + D(Q\|P) - D(R\|P)\big)$, then write out the definition of $D(R\|Q) + D(Q\|P) - D(R\|P)$ explicitly and cancel things down. You'll get something that looks a bit like your $(c-a)\log\frac{c(1-b)}{(1-c)b}$.