# Does KL divergence *ever* satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory, statistical-mechanics

I know that KL divergence does not satisfy the triangle inequality, in that

$$ D(q||p) \leq D(q||r) + D(r||p) $$

is not always true. This statement can be readily proven by providing a counterexample that violates the inequality above.

However, is it true that the KL divergence *never* satisfies the triangle inequality? Or are there some cases where the above inequality holds and some where it does not? I have never seen a general proof that KL divergence never satisfies the triangle inequality, nor have I come across an example where it does satisfy.

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: I don't recall what KL div is, but gut response: what about some trivial cases $p=q=r$? $=0?$ (i.e. you should probably rule out these uninteresting cases)

Comment: I wondered about this some time ago too, but I didn't find anything too convincing. Not answering your question but still related, is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354584/substitute-for-triangle-inequality-for-kullback-leibler-divergence) post.

Comment: Is this really [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)?